# How can detect watch os is ios app closed SWIFTUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

How can I detect with watch os when iOS app is closed? I use swift and watchConnectivity.

Also I use swiftUI

Answer (score 0):

#### On Application Terminate

There is a method as such

```
applicationWillTerminate(_:)
```

*Note By Dávid Pásztor - *You will only have 5 seconds to get your message to the watch or it will not work, so make sure the message you send to the watch will be small and fast.*

This method will detect that the application is being closed and will be cleared from memory. You can then add some connectivity to notify the watch.

**Documentation Here:** 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

---

#### On Application Move To Background

Alternatively, if you want to simply notify the watch whenever the app goes to background, aka goes inactive you can use this method.

```
applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)
```

**Documentation here:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive

Comment: Be aware that `applicationWillTerminate` only allows 5sec of runtime for your iOS app, which might very well not be enough time to communicate over Bluetooth with your watch app.

Comment: It's not working. I now some app this problem solved but how?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SwiftUI

SceneDelegate.swift :

```
func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    sendMessageToWatch()
 }
```